# How do I draw a state diagram for a suspension-queue semaphore?

Tags: semaphore

Here is the question:
Each process may be in different states and different events cause a process to transfer from one state to another; this can be represented using a state diagram. Use a state diagram to explain how a suspension-queue semaphore may be implemented. [10 marks]

Is my diagram correct, or have I misunderstood the question?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DOM3.jpg

It is my understanding that suspended-queue semaphores maintain a list of blocked processes from which to (perhaps randomly) select a process to unblock when the current process has finished its critical section. Hence the waiting state in the state diagram.

pseudocode of suspended_queue_semaphore.

```
struct suspended_queue_semaphore
{
  int count;
  queueType queue;
};
void up(suspended_queue_semaphore s)
{
  if (s.count == 0)
  {
    /* place this process in s.queue /*
    /* block this process */
  }
  else
  {
    s.count = s.count - 1;
  }
}
void down(suspended_queue_semaphore s)
{
  if (s.queue is not empty)
  {
    /* remove a process from s.queue using FIFO */
    /* unblock the process */
  }
  else
  {
    s.count = s.count + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the state diagram for the process or the semaphore, and which semaphore are you talking about. 
In the simplest semaphore: a binary semaphore (i.e. only one process can run) with operations wait() i.e. request to access shared resource and signal() i.e. finished accessing resource.

A state diagram for the process has only two states: Queued (Q) and Running (R) in addition to the Start and Terminate state.
The state diagram would be:

```
START = wait.CAN_RUN
CAN_RUN = suspend.QUEUED + run.RUNNING
QUEUED = run.RUNNING
RUNNING = signal.END
```

The semaphore has two states Empty and Full 
A state diagram for the semaphore would be:

```
START = EMPTY
EMPTY = wait.RUN_PROCCESS + RUN_PROCESS
RUN_PROCESS = run.FULL
FULL = signal.EMPTY + wait.SUSPEND_PROCESS
SUSPEND_PROCESS = suspend.FULL
```

**Edit:** Fixed notation of state diagrams (was backwards sorry my process calculus is rusty) and added internal processes CAN_RUN, SUSPEND_PROCESS and RUN_PROCESS; and internal messages run and suspend.

Explanation: 
The process calls the 'wait' method (up in your pseudo code) and goes to the CAN_RUN state, from there it can either start RUNNING or become QUEUED based on whether it gets a 'run' or 'suspend' message. If QUEUED it can start RUNNING when it receives a 'run' message. If RUNNING it uses 'signal' (down in your pseudo code) before finishing.

The semaphore starts EMPTY, if it gets a 'wait' it goes into RUN_PROCESS issues a 'run' message and becomes FULL. Once FULL any further 'wait' will send it to the SUSPEND_PROCESS state where it issues a 'suspend' to the process. When a 'signal' is received it goes back to EMPTY and it can remain there or go to RUN_PROCESS again based on whether the queue is empty or not (I did not model these internal states, nor did I model the queue as a system.)

Comment: Thank you, would you please provide a link to an article for further reading? I beleive the question is asking to show the implementation of a suspension-queue semaphore (and therefore the impact) on a process, so going from two states of ready(your queued) and running to three states of ready(your queued), running and waiting.

Comment: That's why I asked which semaphore you are referring to. What methods would it support (i.e. what messages are passed). In process calculus a semaphore would be modeled as the interaction between two processes: the semaphore and the well processes/threads/tasks it synchronizes. AFAIK a suspension-queue semaphore is a semaphore in which the suspended process is put in a queue (i.e. first come first served). I don't know the semantics of your three state semaphore, would they be something akin to the C# monitor which has two queues (one for ready to run and one for waiting on a pulse?).

Comment: Thinking about this further, I think the semaphore may interfere with the "dispatched" arrow from ready to running and push the arrow towards the waiting state. I'm not sure how to show this on the diagram

Comment: I have added pseudo code detailing the basic structure and methods of the suspended-queue semaphore as I understand it. You are correct, the queue will operate with a FIFO removal policy.

Comment: @Danny, your pseudo code only contains two messages, up and down, and the process can only be in two states running or suspended. I think you may be over complicating your answer with the cancelled and interruped messages.